# Apply background-image and custom bullet to css heading

Tags: html, css, background-image

So my `<h1>`'s should have individual custom pattern backgrounds and individual image bullets in front of them. The problem is, that I can't apply both style-elements as background-images (I've heard you can have several bg-images with CSS3? But I want to try a more cross-browser compatible way for now.)

html:

```
<div id="content">
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
#content > h1 {
background: url("heading-bg.png") repeat; 
padding: 25px 0 25px 80px;
}
```

Now I tried doing something like this to get the bullet image in front of `<h1>` in css:

```
#content > h1:before {background: url("bullet1.png") no-repeat left;}
```

I could just add another div around my `<h1>`'s and apply the pattern on that, and the bullet direcly on the `<h1>`. Is there another smarter way to achieve my desired effect though?

Thanks!

Comment: Alright, just played around a little and got it to work with this: `#aboutme > h1:before {content: url(../img/personal.png);}` I guess setting a _background-image_ for `h1:before` was a little stupid of me. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, before & after will NOT work unless content is there,

you could do it like this also

```
#content h1:before{
  content:"";
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:url('images/bullet.png');
}
```

Comment: Sounds logical :) Thanks for the reply